# Remove quotes for String in Clickhouse while exporting

Tags: export-to-csv, clickhouse

I'm trying to export data to csv from clickhouse cli.
I have a field which is string and when exported to CSV this field has quotes around it.
I want to export without the `quotes` but couldn't find any setting that can be set.

I went through https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/interfaces/formats but the Values section mentions

> Strings, dates, and dates with times are output in quotes

While for JSON they have a flag that is to be set for removing quotes around Int64 and UInt64

> For compatibility with JavaScript, Int64 and UInt64 integers are enclosed in double quotes by default. To remove the quotes, you can set the configuration parameter output_format_json_quote_64bit_integers to 0.

I was wondering if there is such kind of flag for strings in CSV as well.

I'm exporting using the below command

```
clickhouse client --multiquery --host="localhost" --port="9000" --query="SELECT field1, field2 from tableName format CSV"  > /data/content.csv
```

I want to try removing the quotes from the shell as the last thing if nothing works.

Any help on the way I can remove the quotes while the CSV is generated would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there isn't. However you can easily achieve this by `arrayStringConcat`.

```
SELECT arrayStringConcat([toString(field1), toString(field2)], ',') from tableName format TSV;
```

## Edit

In order to make `Nullable` output as empty string, you might need `if` function.

```
if(isNull(field1), '', assumeNotNull(field1))
```

This works for any types, while `assumeNotNull` alone only works for `String`

Comment: Thanks! That worked.
Just sharing a issue I faced so that you can edit your answer, my fields were nullable string so the function `arrayStringConcat` didn't work for it. I found a work around for it by using `assumeNotNull`. 
So the query became 
```SELECT arrayStringConcat([assumeNotNull(field1), assumeNotNull(field2)], ',') from tableName format TSV;```

Comment: @JigarMehta Ok, it looks like that you want empty string to represent null instead of the fancy "ᴺᵁᴸᴸ" .

Comment: I'm fine with"NULL" but the function arrayStringCocat fails with a nullable string type

Comment: @JigarMehta ah, that makes sense. `Null` gets propagated through out the AST.